# How to Determine Build Process for Inherited Android App

Tags: android, ant, build, apk

I have inherited an unfinished Android App project from a client. There is a lot of work to be done fixing it up, but I cannot even figure out how to build the project! There is no build.xml file, so I don't think they used ANT to build. How can I find out how to build this existing project?
There is a working APK in the project, so it had to have been built successfully at some point.

Comment: And you can't even build the project with eclipse?

Comment: ok so its does compile or not? when you doing rebuild project what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input guys. I am used to doing everything via command line because I'm not a huge fan of Eclipse. Turns out that the original developers of this app were actually using a different IDE called IntelliJ. I have not gotten the app to compile yet but I am now on the right track.